# dc.js move x-axis to zero y value

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Is it possible to move `x`-axis to `y` zero value inside the box of dc.js?

Illustration for understanding the problem:
[image: illustration of moving the axis]

If not, what better way to do this?

Comment: I guess you could move the line without too much difficulty. Moving the tick labels would be kind of a mess, no?